# Adding a third tab in Android studio xml editor

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-plugin

I want to write an Android Studio IDE plugin which will add a third tab (After "Design" and "Text" tab) in the XML file editor view.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a different representation of the layout XML files.

I tried going through the files present under [this page](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/idea133/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/editors/) but I could not find anything useful.

Can anyone help me please ?

EDIT:
This screenshot shows what I am trying to do.
[image: Editor plugin]
This third tab will show the layout in JSON format , the JSON being constructed by my plugin. 
The main purpose of this tab being this : Once the user approves the JSON structure, the plugin will upload the JSON to my server to store my layout on the cloud.

I have gone through IntelliJ plugin creation process. But since I am building a plugin on top of Android's plugin, I am not able to find any good starting point. 
If someone can point me to the source code for the XML layout editor view, I can work from there.

Comment: Your question is much, much too broad to get a good answer. Please ask something more specific and include details on what you've already tried.

Comment: Sure. Will add more details.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me :) and I guess this is simple... you can now make you external tool and distribute for install. In my case when the ViewText windows is deactivated or loses focus, I just close the window automatically...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for a solution which will show the content inside studio itself, in a different tab. I already have a working plugin which can show a popup on clicking an action from tools menu. But I dont know how to show it inline with the XML editor.